# positioning with cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

[Here is the source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8352276/GridWars.zip)

The problem is that the start and end positions of my projectiles are way off.  I have `NSLog`'d all the `CGPoints` and from what I can see the points being fed into the `CCSequence` are correct.  But from what Im seeing on the screen says different.

A big clue to whats wrong I think is that if create a new CCSprite and use it like I do the projectile the pathing works.

Here is the addProjectile method on the game level layer (GameLevels:Level1Layer)

```
-(void)addProjectile:(Projectiles*)projectile
{
    NSLog(@"projectile position %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(projectile.position));
    NSLog(@"wizard position %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(self.wizardHero.position));
    NSLog(@"wizard position worldspace %@",NSStringFromCGPoint([self convertToWorldSpace:self.wizardHero.position]));
    NSLog(@"destination position %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(projectile.destination.position));

    [self addChild:projectile];

    // Determine where we wish to shoot the projectile to
    int realX;

    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(projectile.destination.position,projectile.position);
    if (diff.x > 0)
    {
        realX = (self.tileMap.mapSize.width * self.tileMap.tileSize.width) +
        (projectile.contentSize.width/2);
    } else {
        realX = -(self.tileMap.mapSize.width * self.tileMap.tileSize.width) -
        (projectile.contentSize.width/2);
    }
    float ratio = (float) diff.y / (float) diff.x;
    int realY = ((realX - projectile.position.x) * ratio) + projectile.position.y;
    CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    // Determine the length of how far we're shooting
    int offRealX = realX - projectile.position.x;
    int offRealY = realY - projectile.position.y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX) + (offRealY*offRealY));
    float velocity = 280/1; // 280pixels/1sec
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    // Move projectile to actual endpoint
    id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(projectileMoveFinished:)];
    [projectile runAction:
     [CCSequence actionOne:
      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: realMoveDuration
                          position: realDest]
                       two: actionMoveDone]];

    [self.projectiles addObject:projectile];
}
```

and output from those `NSLog` statements would be (FYI: the projectile is being added from the `self.wizardHero` and thus that is its starting position; destination would be `self.redEnemy`):

> 2013-03-27 10:41:57.295 GridWars[13025:c07] projectile position {105,
>   178}
>
> 2013-03-27 10:41:57.296 GridWars[13025:c07] wizard position {105, 178}
>
> 2013-03-27 10:41:57.297 GridWars[13025:c07] wizard position worldspace
>   {105, 178}
>
> 2013-03-27 10:41:57.298 GridWars[13025:c07] destination position {299,
>   174}
>
> 2013-03-27 11:34:46.608 GridWars[13344:c07] realDest {650,
>   166}
>
> 2013-03-27 11:34:46.608 GridWars[13344:c07] length 545.132080
>
> 2013-03-27 11:34:46.610 GridWars[13344:c07] realMoveDuration 1.946900

I realize that with the super classes I have its a little hard to tell whats going on (kinda why I included the source).  Basically though I have three main super classes which are subclassed from `CCNode`

```
Projectiles : CCNode
        sprite : CCSprite
        destination : GameCharacters
        damage : int


GameLevels : CCNode
        hud : HudLayer
        tileMap : CCTMXTiledMap
        enemies : NSMutablArray
        projectiles : NSMutablArray

GameCharacters : CCNode
        hp : int
        juice : int
        sprite : CCSprite
        selectedTargets : NSMutablArray
        hostLayer : GameLevels
```

Then the three classes that actually implement these

```
        BasicProjectile : Projectiles
        Level1Layer : GameLevels
        WizardHero : GameCharacter
        RedEnemy : GameCharacter
```

Though the problem has slightly evolved I have posted this on the [cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/281826?replies=8#post-447746) and received some help, which got me to this point (seeing projectiles, but path is wrong vs not seeing them at all).  But its been a few days so Hoping for more help.

**GameProjectiles:CCNode**

```
#import "CCNode.h"

//forward declaration because we just need to hold a reference
@class GameCharacters;

@interface GameProjectiles : CCNode

@property(nonatomic, strong) CCSprite * sprite;
@property(nonatomic,strong) GameCharacters * destination;
@property(nonatomic) int damage;
-(id)initWithDestination:(GameCharacters*)Destination;
-(CGSize)contentSize;

@end


#import "GameProjectiles.h"

@implementation GameProjectiles

-(id)initWithDestination:(GameCharacters*)Destination
{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _damage = 0;
        _destination = Destination;
    }
    return self;
}

-(CGSize)contentSize{
    return self.sprite.contentSize;
}

-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    [super setPosition:position];
    self.sprite.position = position;
}
@end
```

**BasicProjectile**

```
#import "GameProjectiles.h"

@interface BasicProjectile : GameProjectiles

@end


#import "BasicProjectile.h"

@implementation BasicProjectile

-(id)initWithDestination:(GameCharacters*)Destination
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.damage = 25;
        self.sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Projectile.png"];
        [self addChild:self.sprite z:1000 ];
        self.destination = Destination;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: What are you seeing on the screen ? log readDest, length and realMoveDuration plz.

Comment: the projectile is far north (top), it might be to the right to much too but hard to see with it being so north. Ill update code above with those values, one sec

Comment: well, if you can see the wizard, and not the projectile, and they both have the same position !!! i can only assume that their 'position' is relative to something different (have a different parent) ... which could also be different from the destination object :).

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I see the projectile.  And after a little more testing If i take out my custom projectile and just put a plain CCSprite in there it all works fine.

Comment: i see the trouble : in GameProjectiles, you override setPosition, and you set the embedded sprite's position to same value. The sprite's position should be (0,0). The way you have it, it ends up (2x,2y)

Comment: negative. I have taken it out and without it I dont see the projectile (possible off screen? idk?).  With it in there thats when I get the projectile I can see but is to far to the top right

Comment: as YvesLeBorg said, it seems very strange that you are positioning some sprite inside overriden setPosition: method of your GameProjectiles class. this sprite can be attached to some other parent and you will not be able to control it's position not relatieve to some parent, but to the whole screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your projectiles and targets are inside a separate CCNode, their bounding box returns their position inside their parent and not in actual screen coordinates (which you want in your case).

To convert the pos you can do like this

```
    CGPoint targetPos = [basicProjectile.destination.sprite.parent convertToWorldSpace:basicProjectile.destination.sprite.position];
    NSLog(@"targetPos  %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(targetPos));
    CGRect targetRect = [self boundingRectForSprite:basicProjectile.destination.sprite andPos:targetPos];

    CGPoint projectilePos = [basicProjectile.sprite.parent convertToWorldSpace:basicProjectile.sprite.position];
    NSLog(@"projectilePos  %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(projectilePos));
    CGRect projectileRect = [self boundingRectForSprite:basicProjectile.destination.sprite andPos:projectilePos];
```

the `boundingRectForSprite` method makes the uses the sprite bounding box and position and then calculates the final rect taking anchor point of (0.5,0.5).

now the `targetRect` and `projectileRect` are of actual screen coordinates.